# Why my public IP is different when I get it from terminal?

Tags: linux, ip

When I get my public IP from terminal using this command:

```
ifconfig ppp0 | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

It is `10.98.181.87`

But when I use external service it reports a different IP:

```
wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo
```

Comment: This is quite obviously not a programming question, so it's off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP addresses that start with `10.` are internal, not public. Somewhere between you and the Internet, there's a router doing [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) so that a relatively small number of IP addresses can be shared amongst a relatively large number of computers.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The IP Address given by `ifconfig` is your local IP of your machine assigned by the router or Access Point (if dhcp is enabled). Where as the IP address seen using `wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo` is the IP address of the router. Even if you do `wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo` from different systems connected to your network,all systems will show the same IP address as you get on your system.